# CASE statement in SQL not working

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm getting an error on the below code and despite searching for an answer haven't been able to figure it out.

Error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CASE'

My code:

```
SELECT     
    PS_Margin.[Project Profit by Person %], 
    PS_Long.[Days Between], PS_Long.[Entered Hours], 
    PS_Long.[Maximum Month Worked], PS_Long.[Minimum Month Worked], 
    PS_Long.[Project ID], PS_Proj.[Project Name], 
    ((PS_Util_Sum.[Current Month Forecast Hours] + PS_Util_Sum.[Next Month Forecast Hours] + PS_Util_Sum.[Next Monthplus1 Forecast Hours])/
    (PS_Util_Sum.[Current Month Adj Avail Hours] + PS_Util_Sum.[Next Month Adj Avail Hours] + PS_Util_Sum.[Next Monthplus1 Adj Avail Hours])) AS [90 Day Forecast Percent],
    ((PS_Util_Sum.[Current Month Goal Hours] + PS_Util_Sum.[Next Month Goal Hours] + PS_Util_Sum.[Next Monthplus1 Goal Hours])/
    (PS_Util_Sum.[Current Month Adj Avail Hours] + PS_Util_Sum.[Next Month Adj Avail Hours] + PS_Util_Sum.[Next Monthplus1 Adj Avail Hours])) AS [90 Day Goal Percent],
    (PS_Util_Sum.[Current Month Forecast Hours] + PS_Util_Sum.[Next Month Forecast Hours] + PS_Util_Sum.[Next Monthplus1 Forecast Hours]) AS [90 Day Projected Production],
    PS_Util_Sum.[PYTD Charged Hours] / PS_Util_Sum.[PYTD Adj Avail Hours] AS [PYTD Utilization],
    PS_Util_Sum.[PYTD Goal Hours] / PS_Util_Sum.[PYTD Adj Avail Hours] AS [PYTD Utilization Goal],
    [PYTD Utilization] - [PYTD Utilization Goal] AS [PYTD Var to Goal],
    [90 Day Goal Percent] - [90 Day Forecast Percent] AS [90Day Var]
    (CASE 
        WHEN PS_Util_Sum[PYTD Var to Goal %]> -.1 AND PS_Util_Sum[90Day Var] >= 0  
           THEN 1
        WHEN PS_Util_Sum[PYTD Var to Goal %]<= -.1 AND PS_Util_Sum[90Day Var] >= 0 
           THEN 2
        WHEN PS_Util_Sum[PYTD Var to Goal %]> -.1 AND PS_Util_Sum[90Day Var]< 0 
           THEN 3
        ELSE 4 
    END) AS [Quad Group]
FROM         
    dbo.PS_Emp 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.PS_Margin ON PS_Emp.[USID] = PS_Margin.[Emp or Vendor ID] 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.PS_Util_Sum ON PS_Emp.[USID] = PS_Util_Sum.[Employee_ID] 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    dbo.PS_Long ON PS_Emp.[USID] = PS_Long.[Employee ID]
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.PS_Proj ON PS_Long.[Project ID] = PS_Proj.[Project ID]
```

Comment: You're missing a comma.  `, (CASE ...`.

Comment: It's a `CASE` _expression_, not a statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typographical error.

Change `[90 Day Goal Percent] - [90 Day Forecast Percent] AS [90Day Var]` to `[90 Day Goal Percent] - [90 Day Forecast Percent] AS [90Day Var],` (it's missing a comma at the end).

Comment: That did it. Sometimes its something very simple.

Comment: @TessD This is when not using long column/object names and good formatting come into it's own. Typographical errors are much easier to find in well formatted, and succinct code. if you need a very descriptive Column name, use your presentation layer. Having a column with the name like `PS_Util_Sum.[Next Month Adj Avail Hours]` will really bloat out your code.